# Framework and database adapter with Hexagonal Architecture and DCI pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, adapter, hexagonal-architecture

I try to design a web based application in Ruby. I have developed a simple core application implementing DCI paradigm in hexagonal architecture without framework and database. There are small hexagons in core hexagon and adapters such as web, database, logs etc. Every hexagons run itself without database and framework. How can I provide relation with database models and entity classes as independent with database in this approach. I want to change framework from Rails to Sinatra in future or database. In fact, how can I implement database adapter or framework adapter that is exactly isolated rails and mongodb in this core Hexagon. Any ideas?

Comment: DCI is not a pattern it's a paradigm just like OO is not a pattern but a paradigm

Answer (score 4):

What about [ROM](http://rom-rb.org/) (Ruby Object Mapper).

There is also [MiniMapper](https://github.com/joakimk/minimapper) and [DataMappify](https://github.com/fredwu/datamappify).